# Is just telling the OP that they can fix their problem by upgrading to a newer version of a component really an answer?

Tags: support, answers, not-an-answer, specific-answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56009618/9609843

[image]

I can't understand why it is considered an answer (I got declined NAA flag on it). Can somebody explain? It should be a comment IMHO.

Comment: eh, yea, it's an answer... just not a good one. It would be better if they tracked down the bug that was fixed between the versions.

Comment: It attempts to answer the question- so NAA flag wouldn't apply. A downvote might be a better action since it isn't a good answer.

Comment: Why isn't it valuable to know a problem is fixed in a specific version?

Comment: Why do you think it's not an answer?  You're the one claiming it's not an answer and that it needs to be deleted.  Why *isn't* that an attempt to answer the question?

Comment: If the asker wants to solve his problem in his version, answer "this works fine in another version" is not an answer.

Comment: fortunately (or unfortunately), the OP didn't add any such requirement or even specify which version is in use.

Comment: It isn't always possible to fix a problem in the version you are using and sometimes the only fix is to upgrade.

Comment: My 1963 Chevrolet Corvair doesn't seem to have built-in XM satellite radio. Will changing the oil fix this?

Answer (score 26):

Yes, it really is.

It contains all the necessary components of an answer:

- It is **relevant** to the question,
- It is written in a **comprehensible** manner, and
- It provides a **solution** to the question.

An answer that tells you there is a bug or lack of support for a feature in a particular version of the software, and confirms that updating to a newer version solves the problem, is not only a *valid* answer, but a *useful* answer. Especially when it cites specific, traceable version numbers.

The only way to make that answer better would be if it provided a reference to support the claim—for example, a link to the project's bug tracker, showing that the bug has since been resolved in version 4.17.47. However, this is not a requirement for a valid answer.

Deleting that answer would not help anyone, which is why I declined the flag.

I can't see any reason why it would be better as a comment. Because it's short? No, comments aren't meant for short answers. [They're meant for requesting clarification or suggesting improvements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

**Related reading: [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)**